Put TURN server as a candidate, but not as the default address in PJSUA2 Android
I am building a voip app on android using PJSUA2. Currently, calls are working except for on certain public WIFI networks, where turn seems to solve the problem. However, setting setTurnEnabled to true in the account NAT config defaults the c=IN IP4 line in the SDP to the turn server, seemingly forcing all calls to go through it. I would like to only include it in the ice candidates, so it is used only if other options fail. Is that possible?
Code for enabling the turn server in the account creation:
accCfg.getNatConfig().setTurnServer("x.x.x.x:3478");
accCfg.getNatConfig().setTurnEnabled(true);
accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);

EDIT: Still facing this issue, but I have now noticed that the use of TURN is mostly required on NAT type 6 (Symmetric), which is a known problematic NAT type to work with. As a workaround, I am currently looking into storing the account configuration, and upon making a call, checking for the NAT type and enabling the turn sever if it is symmetric. The reason I don't do this when the account is first created is because I occasionally create the account right as the application starts, and checking for the NAT type in this state give a PJ_EPENDING error. At this point, if anyone has a more viable workaround I would be very happy to hear it.
